# TYPO3 - How to check if a news article has a certain parent category with fluid

Tags: typo3, fluid, tx-news

How can I check that a news article has a certain parent category in m'y Fluid template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can help :

```
<f:for each="{newsItem.categories}" as="category">
    <f:if condition="{category.parent.uid} == theCatIdYouAreSearchingFor">
        do your stuff here...
    </f:if>
</f:for>
```

Comment: I propose `<f:if condition="{category.parent.uid} == theCatIdYouAreSearchingFor">` as he asked for the parent category

Comment: This works too `<f:if condition="{newsItem.firstCategory.parentcategory.uid} == theCatIdYouAreSearchingFor">`